# Applications of bayesian inference to external ballistics?

Tags: bayes

I'm reading "The theory that would not die" by Sharon Bertsch McGrayne (Fine book. Strongly recommended to everyone). The author says that bayesian inference has been used for ballistics applications at least three times in the last three centuries:

1) By Joseph Louis François Bertrand (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Louis_Fran%C3%A7ois_Bertrand), between 1880 and 1940, for field artillery firing direction.

2) By Jean Baptiste Eugène Estienne (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Baptiste_Eug%C3%A8ne_Estienne), immediately before WWI, again for field artillery firing direction.

3) By Andrey Kolmogorov (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Kolmogorov), during the WWII, for field artillery firing and for air bombing direction.

Unfortunately, I was unable to find any more information regarding this particular use of bayesian inference. Every article/book I was able to find just asserts that bayesian inference (or at least Bayes's Theorem) was used for external ballistic applications. They do not explain which specific problem was solved using Bayes's Theorem and how it was solved.

Can somebody address me to any useful source of information regarding the applications of bayesian inference to external ballistics?

As an alternative: can somebody supply me with any example of such applications? Simple real-world/historical cases or near-real-world examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As Far as I know, the Total Probability theorem (The integral formula of the Total Probability as well) is used in Artillery fire, to estimate the incapacitation of personnel from fragmentation ammunition or/and from the shock wave of the explosion (usually in nuclear explosions). 
 http://gklimi.wix.com/physicsmathapp/studies
See Study: Estimation of casualties from Fragmentation Ammunitions
and Estimation of the Destructive Power of Meteorites and Meteors.

I do not remember any use of Bayes Theorem in exterior ballistics. Of course the Bayes Theorem is used in artillery fire.